# Let $Y,Z$ be independent stochastic variables, $Y \sim Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X := Y+Z$. Find $f_{X,Y}$ for $(X,Y)$ using transformation theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y,Z$ be independent stochastic variables, $Y \sim Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X := Y+Z$.

Find $f_{Y,Z}$ for $(Y,Z)$ and $f_{X,Y}$ for $(X,Y)$ using **transformation theorem**.

Since $Y,Z$ are independent we have $f_{Y,Z}(u,z) = f_Y(y) f_Z(z)$ right?

Also using a theorem I can conclude $X\sim N(0+0,1+1)=N(0,2)$.

However, I've tried to use a transformation, but it's really hard to understand. Could someone provide an example ?

Comment: What kind of transformation do you want to use?

Comment: The one where we have two one-to-one functions of the RV's and use the Jacobian of their derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly state, 
$$
f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=f_Z(z)f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12(z^2+y^2)},\quad (y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$
due to independence. Now, $(X,Y)=g(Z,Y)$ with $g(z,y)=(z+y,y)$ which has inverse function $h(x,y)=(x-y,y)$. If $h_1(x,y)=x-y$ and $h_2(x,y)=y$ denotes the coordinate functions of $h$, then the Jacobian of $h$ is
$$
J(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}(x,y)\\
\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial y}(x,y)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $\det J(x,y)=1$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus we conclude that $(X,Y)$ has density
$$
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=|\det J(x,y)|f_{Z,Y}(h(x,y))=f_{Z,Y}(x-y,y)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 [(x-y)^2+y^2]}.
\end{align}
$$